# Gedit User Interface Language is not English, how do I change it?

Tags: java, user-interface, gedit

I'm a novice to this whole thing, and while I'm reading *Learn Java the Hard Way* , it says,

"Installing a Decent Text Editor (gedit)
1. On Ubuntu, gedit is already installed by default. It’s called “Text Editor”. If you search for it in the Dash, you’ll find it with “gedit” or “text”.
If it’s not installed on your Linux distro, use your package manager to install it.
2. Makesureyoucangettoiteasilybyright-clickingonitsiconintheLauncherbarandselecting
“Lock to Launcher”.
3. Run gedit so we can change some of the defaults to be better for programmers:
A. In the menu bar, open the “Edit” menu then choose “Preferences”. B. In the “View” tab, put a check mark next to “Display line numbers” C. Make sure there’s not a check mark next to “Enable text wrapping”
D. Switch to the “Editor” tab and change Tab width: to 4.
E. Put a check mark next to “Enable automatic indentation”"

I tried to download Gedit from web, but it turned out to be in another language that I have no idea about. How do I switch it to English?

[this is what's shown on my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeNlV.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar of gedit there is a menu option labelled Tools, in there is a Set Language option.  The Tools menu will be The 5th one over from the word "gedit" in the top menu.

```
Tools > Set Language
```

[image: Screenshot of Mac OS version of gedit]

Removed the part about doing an 'apt-get install' because I just noticed the screen shot you included which shows you're using an Apple.

Comment: Thanks so much # Momus for your detailed answer. But u see, I downloaded Homebrew, and it seems like I can't use sudo command anymore.

Comment: I edited my answer because I didn't see the screenshot the first time.  In the top menu of your interface the Tools menu option is the one that starts with "Epya...", fifth over from the left, starting from where it says "gedit".

Comment: Also, the "Set Language" option should be the third option from the top in the Tools menu.